Proper site to ask how to construct an Archimedes' screw
Well, the title says (nearly) all. I want to know how our forefathers could have done this without modern materials and tools.
I have asked this on Engineering Meta, https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/685/5217 and have been redirected here.
History looks like a good sit to ask this, but I'm not really sure, so I'm asking on meta first.

Personally, I think that would probably be on-topic. However,others here may disagree, and it only takes 3 such users to close a question.
You might also consider the History of Science and Math site. Not only is it a more focused history-based site, but I believe they are a likely a bit more generous with marginal questions (that are arguably within their domain) than we are.

Thank you for the warning. Getting a question closed would not be the worst that could happen:  I imagine lots of down-votes combined with a nonsensical answer that prevents me from deleting the question.
